# TableView skips a few cells to display data from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

So I'm able to parse the JSON data but when I try to display it in TableView, I get the first row displayed, and then maybe the sixth data and so on, like so:

[image]

This is how I retrieve my data:

```
- (void)getData{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hart88/198f29ec5114a3ec3460/raw/8dd19a88f9b8d24c23d9960f3300d0c917a4f07c/cake.json"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *jsonError;
    id responseData = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                       options:kNilOptions
                       error:&jsonError];
    if (!jsonError){
        self.objects = responseData;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.objects);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
    }

}
```

And this is how I display them in cellforRowAt:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CakeCell *cell = (CakeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CakeCell"];
[self.tableView registerClass:[CakeCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CakeCell"];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

    NSDictionary *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = object[@"title"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = object[@"desc"];


    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:object[@"image"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [cell.cakeImageView setImage:image];

});

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why do you dispatch them in `cellForRow`? Just use the main thread, you shouldn't access the cells in background thread. That might be the cause right there.

Comment: @libec I use them to avoid lag when I scroll tableView. Even if I don't use dispatch, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you post rest of the code?

Comment: @libec I updated the OP with the complete methods. What other methods do you think you need to look at?

Comment: As suggested by libec , first remove `dispatch` block from this code and then please put this line `[self.tableView registerClass:[CakeCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CakeCell"];` in `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: **Never** register cells in `cellForRow` and **never** register cells after (re)using them. If you are not using extra XIBs don't register cells at all. Another *don't* is: Don't load data synchronously with `[NSData dataWithContents` in `cellForRow`

Comment: fetch the data in background thread  and reload the table view main thread. Also remove the dispatch async code from the cellForRowAtIndexPath. You still need to load the image asynchronously and set the image in main thread.

Comment: @vadian @3stud1ant3 I implemented as you suggested, but when I register cells before `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, like in `viewDidLoad`, I don't see them displayed.

Comment: Do you use extra XIBs or is the cell designed in the storyboard? If the latter it's wrong to register the cell. Delete the line.

Comment: @vadian I must've missed it the last time you said it. Works perfectly now! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you access the UIKit elements from the background thread. You can refactor it in the following way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CakeCell *cell = (CakeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CakeCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CakeCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CakeCell"];

    NSDictionary *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = object[@"title"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = object[@"desc"];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {        
        NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:object[@"image"]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.cakeImageView setImage:image];
        });        
    });    
    return cell;
}
```

If you need to pefrom some UI update as a result of a background operation always wrap this code in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})` invocation